# How searches with criteria should be implemented in Event sourcing with CQRS

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Let's say I need to query for all entities which comply with given criteria. My biggest confusion is about where the data should be taken from. I guess we have two option, either query event store itself or ask some other projection storage solution(have no idea - maybe some DB or what). It maybe depend on the amount of events processed. How will the implementation look like?

1. asking directly the event store we will query all entities and then filter them in application?
2. using DB we will just query the underlying table, which is taylored for specific criteria search

What about performance?.

In event store the best one can do is probably to create some snapshots, not sure anyway how to list complex so called "aggregates". In DB we will have nearly the same count of rows as events, which will end up in extensive DB optimalization. Not to mention that this DB can be dropped anytime and filled again which I completely cannot imagine. Do I get the things right or am I completely of the track?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t quite have the proper mental view of CQRS yet.  The C of CQRS is for commands which only update data.  They instantiate an entity in memory using events in the event store, make the proper changes, then store those changes back to the event store.  This side is not meant for adhoc queries.  Think of the Command side as data you are only allowed to access via the primary key.

The read side is where you would query for all entities with a particular attribute.  The read side is built in a DB (not an event store) by special code that listens to the event store and adds/updates rows in the read side DB to keep it up to date.  Note that the read side DB is not third normal form – data is often duplicated and there are very few foreign keys.

So, while it is technically possible to query most event stores for specific attributes, but it’s clumsy since that’s not what they were designed for.  To get collections of objects you query the read side.

Walking through a typical example

1. User arrives on your site and clicks a button to see a list of blue T-shirts.  You query the read side for all Inventory entities with Type="TShirt" and Color="Blue", and return this list to the user screen with a counter of how many are in stock.
2. The user clicks on a t-shirt so you query the read side for details on the shirt and a picture.  Show the user that screen using that info.
3. The user adds the t-shirt to the cart.  You execute the AddItemToCart command which creates a CartCreated event, then an ItemAddedToCart event, then an InventoryDecremented event.
4. The read side is subscribing to the event source and sees these events, so it updates its tables appropriately.
5. A second user comes in that also wants a blue t-shirt, but she sees that inventory is now 0 since the previous person got the last one.  All that info comes from the read side DB only, not the event source (command side).

If you keep the two sides separate in your mind, many questions of how to implement something just fade away.

Comment: I occupy myself couple of hours now about this requirement: how to validate username is valid before creating the UserCreatedEvent. Or in your example how to check inventory before InventoryDecremented is made? What is your take on this?

Comment: Event Sourcing is designed with eventual consistency in mind so immediate consistency is a bit tough.  With eventual consistency you would assume the inventory is available at purchase time and give the user an success message, then later when the event is processed and you find the inventory is not available, you send the user an email.  Note that "eventual" is normally a few seconds, but the point is the data is not available during the processing of the OrderCreated command.

Comment: For immediate consistency, username is a bad example because it's probably the primary key so it's easy to determine if that username already exists while processing the command, therefore you just send back the error message.  A better example is available credit when making a purchase.  In that case you would create a CreditReserved event that prevents another simultaneous process from using up the credit, then check if there is sufficient credit and debit it.  The read side would see the CreditReserved and consider that credit used up so it's not available.

Comment: What if the username is not the key. I have read that uniqueness is common problem with miriad of solution i.e. aggregate or simple table with all registered usernames

Comment: There is no one standard way of dealing with this in ES so you need to do a custom approach.  For this particular case, I would keep a one column table with username as a primary key.  Try to insert the new one and if the DB insert fails, the username is taken.  It's clumsy but it works.  If you do not have a large number of username creations the better way is for the command to hit a report side API to ask if the username is already taken.  This produces a race condition, though, so you need to take special precautions against that.

Comment: I'm really interest in the special precautions mentioned. If you will check read model for that username and you will not see it there( as the other request is not yet written). How can you resolve this. You will find later that the user is taken what you should do? Rise RegistrationCanceledEvent?Notify the user his registration is not valid? Can you please suggest what you meant by those precaucions?

Comment: First let’s discuss the issue so we know what we’re dealing with.  The race condition occurs because Player1 creates the username “justme” at exactly the same time as Player2 creates the same username. Just by luck, Player1’s request is processed first.  The uniqueness is tested using the Read Model and it’s available so Player1 gets the username and a UsernameCreated event is published.  Then Player2’s request comes in and since the UsernameCreated event has not been processed by the read side yet, Player2 also gets that username and an identical UsernameCreated event is published.

Comment: The first way of dealing with this is exception handling.  When the read side tries to process the second UsernameCreated event, it finds Player1’s version and throws an exception, creating a UsernameInvalid event an notifying the user they need to change their username.  This is the proper way of doing things when using ES.

Comment: The second way is to make the username creation process synchronous.  Add a UsernameCreatedHandled event that is generated by the read side after the UsernameCreated event is processed.  The Command side will create the UsernameCreated event then block while listening for either the UsernameCreatedHandled event or the UsernameInvalid event.  Depending on which is received, the command side proceeds appropriately.

Comment: Note that this requires a RequestID be generated by the command side and put into the payload of the UsernameCreated event, then copied by the read side into either the UsernameCreatedHandled event or the UsernameInvalid event.  This is so the command side knows it received the proper event for what it’s trying to do.

Comment: I'm starting to believe pure  CRUD will be better. Maybe trying to put ES everywhere is bad decision. Maybe separating the user management to non-ES microservice will be wiser.

Comment: That sounds like a smart move.  You're right that not everything has to be CQRS.  It's useful for complex domains where where immediate consistency is unnecessary and/or difficult to do.  If something can be done with just CRUD then that's the best way to go.  I would still generate the events, though, on UsernameCreated to enable CQRS in other parts of the system.

Answer (score 0):

**Event Sourcing:** is a way of developing an application in which all information is persisted as events. For more info refer [here](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)

**Example:** If we are developing a banking software, the events that we store will be something like below

- User1, transacted : 100, reference : "xyz", Date : 11th October 2018
- User1, transacted : -100, reference : "xyza", Date : 18th October 2018
- and so on...

Now if the User1 wants to debit his/her account, then we pull all the events from his/her stream and replay to get the balance. And if he/she has sufficient balance then we debit his/her account by adding one debit event.

This process takes a bit of time, and it is generally done only when there is a need to write in to the system (Writes are less common than reads in most systems). Though this takes a bit of time, it gives us the benefit of audit-ablity, security and running analytics.

The difficulties in a event sourced system are for querying. If we need to get a list of users who deposited more than 10000 units in a quarter, then its going to be difficult and time consuming as we need to replay the every users stream. To solve this we can use CQRS.

**CQRS:** is a pattern of developing software where the writes are done by one application and reads are done by another application. More information available [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). The write application and read application could communicate with each other (may be by messaging). The read application could maintain it's own database and store the information in the shape that is comfortable for querying. So when the read application gets a message, it converts the message that is suitable for it's own db schema and store it.

The read application will eventually (probably in couple of seconds) be consistent with the write application. The read application will be able to handle queries quickly very quickly as its database schema is designed for it.

**Now answering your question:**

- There is a bit of time taken for updating data in the write appliation. The write application replays all the events (or the events after snapshot) before any update. As long as the aggregates are small and we employ proper snapshotting techniques the performance is not bad.
- The read model has it's own database, the schema is designed to suit querying. Many a times we don't worry about redundant data in the read database. This is designed to make queries fast.
- We could decide to throw the read applications (models) data and rebuild it in another shape to suite new queries as the source of truth is the events stored in the write application (model).

Comment: So in case I would like to rewrite my application to CQRS, I will for the read side just drop all update code(CUD) and will just use the R portion of it on top of some event listening, right? It will be maybe more denormalized but really close. Now I have state at two places event store and read-side DB, which maybe is not bad just space consuming. What about the need to do some really complex validation before the command can be executed. Without the access to separated read-side DB, I am left with asking the event store directly, right?

Comment: The read side will mainly have the R portion and event listening. The event listening part should CUD part in that database. You could have it normalized or denormalized here. They have their own tradeoffs.  Having the data in two sides is okay (not bad), the space is not so much of a problem as it is cheap these days. The validations will generally need only one aggregate, so you should be able to replay one stream and do it. Its not advisable to depend on read model and it only eventually consistent

Comment: I'm really not confident in event store querying capabilities. They usually use event key even though you can probably have more indexes in some solution. Anyway I am not really clear how I will use different event data to do the validation before proceeding.

Comment: What kind of querying capability you are expecting? I use only 2. 1- Get all events on a stream since event Id. 2- And get all events on all stream since event id

Comment: How do you search entities connected with specific object ie. user? How do you filter the event types? You do this programatically? How do you know where to start the search?

Comment: Can you give an example in the banking context ?

Comment: Account state for starter. There must be some id binding events together. How do you get balance for specific user? You get the ID from UI and you will get all event for account with owner equals the ID. Where do you start and how do you query for BalanceChangeEvent for specified user?Note we are talking about validation not read query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201869/discussion-between-nachiappan-kumarappan-and-zveratko).